# Montar árvore de nós

Tags: php, algoritmo

Preciso montar uma estrutura semelhante a uma arvore genealógica, porém com apenas um elemento Pai que pode ter "n" filhos, e cada filho também pode ter "n" filhos. A estrutura abaixo ilustra um teste que alimentaria essa arvore.

Aqui é o código que deve testar a estrutura da árvore:

```
$arvore = new No('Thiago'); //Aqui cria-se a arvore, ou elemento Pai

$no = $arvore->addFilho('Alan'); //Alan deveria ser um filho de Thiago, seguindo a estrutura
$no->addFilho('Thiago'); //Já nessa linha, a ideia era que fosse adicionado a Alan, um filho chamado Thiago
//assim como a linha de baixo, resultando em dois filhos para Alan.
// Mas me resulta um erro no PHP:
// Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function addFilho() on null 
$no->addFilho('Thiago');

$no = $arvore->addFilho('Robson'); //Robson também seria filho de Thiago, que é a Arvore/elemento Pai
$no->addFilho('Maurício'); //E mauricio seria filho de Robson, assim como Bruno e Xuxa
$no1 = $no->addFilho('Bruno');
// Rodolpho e Guilherme são filhos do Bruno
$no1->addFilho('Rodolpho');
$no1->addFilho('Guilherme');
$no->addFilho('Xuxa');

$arvore->addFilho('Eduardo');
$arvore->addFilho('Alexandre')->addFilho('Gabriel');

echo "\n".$arvore->busca('Thiago'); //Deve retornar true, pois existe no nó da arvore
echo "\n".$arvore->busca('Xuxa'); //Deve retornar true, pois existe no nó da arvore, como filho
echo "\n".$arvore->busca('Fábio'); //Deve retornar false pois não existe no nó da arvore
```

Agora entra a parte que eu não estou sabendo desenvolver, que é a Classe No:

```
class No {

public $arvore = array();
public $filho = array();

function __construct($arvore){
    $this->$arvore[] = $arvore;
}

public function getArvore(){
    return $this->arvore[0];
}

public function addFilho($filho){
    if(!isset($this->filho)){
        $this->filho[] = $filho;
        $this->arvore[getArvore()][] = $filho;
    } else{
        $this->arvore[][$filho] = $filho;
        $this->filho[$filho] = $filho;
    }
} 

public function busca($elemento){

    foreach ($this->arvore as $node) {
        if($node == $elemento){
            return true;
        }
    } 
    return false; 
  }
}
```

Entendo que devem haver alguns erros de OO, e talvez alguma lógica incorreta também, porém não consigo pensar em alguma forma de resolver, além do que fiz até agora.

[image: Uma ideia da estrutura seria isso]

Comment: Qual é sua dúvida específica? Vi alguns problemas no seu código. Uma coisa que as pessoas nunca entendem sobre OO é que só dá para fazer certo com todos requisitos muito bem detalhados, colhidos de forma correta e já especificado tudo o que deve fazer. Sem isso qualquer coisa que faça pode estar errado porque há um erro anterior. OOP não faz projetos ruins magicamente se tornarem bons.

Comment: minha dúvida é como implementar, de maneira correta, a classe No, para que o primeiro trecho de código funcione como o esperado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu problema nada tem a ver com orientação a objeto, é só um algoritmo imperativo simples que está errado. Pelo menos o foco principal. Na pergunta original não tinha que quer toda a solução, o que torna a pergunta ampla.

```
public function busca($elemento){
    foreach ($this->arvore as $node) if($node == $elemento) return true;
    return false;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Algorithm/SearchCollection.php).

Quando está fazendo uma busca sequencial simples de fato deve encerrar o algoritmo assim que ele achar algo, então o `return true` neste caso está correto. Mas o que deve fazer se olhando para aquele elemento ele não é achado? O código original está encerrando a busca dizendo que não achou, só que você só olhou um elemento, e não vai outra os outros? O correto é continuar o laço até achar algum, não deve tomar qualquer ação se o elemento não base com o que está buscando. Apenas se o laço for até o fim e olhar todos os elementos da coleção de dados é que podemos afirmar que o dado não existe lá, todas comparações falharam e encerrou sem achar nada, aí sim deve encerrar o algoritmo com um `return` false`.

A conceituação toda desta classe parece estar errada, mas como disse nos comentários, sem entender exatamente o que precisa é difícil falar algo.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda na busca. Mas o que preciso realmente é gerar uma estrutura semelhante a uma arvore genealógica, porém com um 'Pai' que pode ter n filhos, e cada filho pode ter n filhos também. No caso, $arvore = new No('Thiago') diz que a arvore em sí, ou elemento pai, se chama Thiago. Já em $no = $arvore->addFilho('Alan') define o primeiro filho se chamando Alan, e Alan teria dois filhos Thiago. A mesa lógica deveria se aplicar para os outros exemplos de teste, porém quando declaro $no->addFilho('Thiago') o PHP resulta em Uncaught Error: Call to a member function addFilho() on null

Comment: Agora você já está coloando outro erro, a pergunta já ficou não clara ou ampla.

Comment: Vou reformular então

Comment: Acredito que agora tenha ficado mais clara minha duvida